# Node.js native addons: where is node_api.h located?

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp, node-addon-api

I'm trying to create a native addon for Node.js and when I include

```cpp
#include <napi.h>
```

The Intelli Sense of VS Code says that it cannot detect where `node_api.h` is located (it's included by `napi.h`).

`node-gyp build` works well and it compiles. But I do not understand where is that header in the system and where `node-gyp` gets it from? I need to add the path to the Intelli Sense options and to better understand the process of building in general.

I'm playing with [this code example](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples/tree/master/1_hello_world/node-addon-api).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have run a full search on disk C (I'm on Windows 10), and found out that the header file `node_api.h` is located in

```
C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\<NodeVersion>\include\node
```

as well as other headers like `v8.h`.

If you delete that folder, `node-gyp build` no longer works. `node-gyp configure` downloads all headers again and restores the above mentioned folder.

Comment: In my computer it is in `C:/Users/<user>/.node-gyp/<version>/include/node`

Comment: how did you resolve the intellisense without hardcoding your `<user>` path?

Comment: nice working well, but wondering how to avoid to hardcode the username and the nodeversion

Comment: Side note: On linux, if installed globally with default node settings, they are in: "/usr/include/node"

Answer (score 1):

Are you using extension ms-vscode.cpptools by Microsoft? Then you should just add the path for the header files used by napi to your include path in VSCode:
Move your cursor over the include line with the error -> chose "Quick Fix" -> there should be an option for setting include path options (exact naming is language specific) -> new tab opens, add the path under "include path"

The header files are located in appdata as described by RussCoder.

Alternatively see:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/customize-default-settings-cpp

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kind of old, but here was my work around to avoid hardcoding. If you aren't using vscode, this probably helps a bit more. I used the below function to generate a compile_flags.txt for clangd
After building with node-gyp, there should be a file `config.gypi`, which is similar to json. there is a property called `nodedir` which should point to the include path. here's a function that could help find this:
This should hopefully be platform independent.

```js
const fsp = require('fs/promises');
const { existsSync, readFileSync } = require('fs');
const assert = require('node:assert');

const findnodeapih = () => {
    assert(existsSync("./build"), "Haven't built the application once yet. Make sure to build it");
    const dir = readFileSync("./build/config.gypi", 'utf8');
    const nodedir_line = dir.match(/"nodedir": "([^"]+)"/);
    assert(nodedir_line, "Found no matches")
    assert(nodedir_line[1]);
    console.log("node_api.h found at: ", nodedir_line[1]);
    return nodedir_line[1]+"/include/node";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `node-addon-api` module.

The headers can be included via `require('node-addon-api').include` or you can find it inside `node_modules/node-addon-api` folder.

https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/blob/master/doc/setup.md

Comment: `require('node-addon-api').include` and `node_modules/node-addon-api` is the same folder as I see in `node_modules/node-addon-api/index.js`. There is `napi.h` but there is no `node_api.h`.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, I found (given an install of Node version 16.17.0) that my `node_api.h` was stored at `~/.node-gyp/16.17.0/include/node/node_api.h`. So I was able to include it via the path `~/.node-gyp/16.17.0/include/**`.

So, to get proper Intellisense in VS Code, I edited this config file. Quite a few fields were already set up for me by default, but all I changed with regards to this question was to add an extra path to `includePath`.

`.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json`:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "~/.node-gyp/16.17.0/include/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

You can avoid hard-coding the version by changing the path to:

`~/.node-gyp/**`

... but be warned that if you have multiple versions of node installed, you'll end up including duplicate headers (and having a bad time). So alternatively, you could manually set up a symlink at `~/.node-gyp/current` that points to whichever version of node you're using, I guess, and set your path as `~/.node-gyp/current/**`. Or just point at one installed version of node arbitrarily and hope that the headers don't change that much between versions..!

Comment: I ran `npm install -g node-gyp && node-gyp install` on my Homebrew-installed Node 20 on macOS 13.4 but I still don't see a ~/.node-gyp directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **nvm** to manage Node.js, `node_api.h` is located in `${HOME}/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/include/node`.